# Using loops to call multiple pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am new to python3 and trying to do chisquared tests on columns in a pandas dataframe. My columns are in pairs: observed_count_column_1, expected count_column_1, observed_count_column_2, expected_count_column_2 and so on. I would like to make a loop to get all column pairs done at once.

I succeed doing this if I specify column index integers or column names manually.
This works

```py
from scipy.stats import chisquare
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv (r'count.csv')
chisquare(df.iloc[:,[0]], df.iloc[:,[1]])
```

This, trying with a loop, does not:

```py
from scipy.stats import chisquare
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv (r'count.csv')
for n in [0,2,4,6,8,10]:    
    chisquare(df.iloc[:,[n]], df.iloc[:,[n+1]]
```

The loop code does not seem to run at all and I get no error but no output either.

I was wondering why this is happening and how can I actually approach this?

Thank you,
Dan

Comment: Loop does not assign anything and does not print anything. So naturally, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building a data frame of chi-square results from list of tuples, then assign column names as indicators for observed and expected frequencies (subsetting even/odd columns by indexed notation):

```
# CREATE DATA FRAME FROM LIST IF TUPLES 
# THEN ASSIGN COLUMN NAMES
chi_square_df = (pd.DataFrame([chisquare(df.iloc[:,[n]], df.iloc[:,[n+1]]) \ 
                                for n in range(0,11,2)],
                              columns = ['chi_sq_stat', 'p_value'])
                   .assign(obs_freq = df.columns[::2],
                           exp_freq = df.columns[1::2])
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

chisquare() function returns two values so you can try this:

```
for n in range(0, 11, 2):
    chisq, p = chisquare(df.iloc[:,[n]], df.iloc[:,[n+1]]
    print('Chisq: {}, p-value: {}'.format(chisq, p))
```

You can find what it returns in the docs here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions. Using the information from Parfait comment, that loops don't print I managed to find a solution, although not as elegant as their own solution above.

```
for n in range(0, 11, 2):
    print(chisquare(df.iloc[:,[n]], df.iloc[:,[n+1]]))
```

This gives the expected results.

Dan